# how to put image and text on map autocomplete fragment?

Tags: android, git, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QRcK.jpg)How to put image and text in this map places autocomplete fragment in xml file

```
This is my xml code
```

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cardView">
        <fragment  android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are attempting please?

Comment: plz be more specific in what you want, share with us examples, and show us more of the code you have already done.

Comment: I am developing an app like Uber and want to take  to and from location using google place Api and above place autocomplete fragment for that it will give default view but i want to put some text to show from location and image on this how can i do ?

Comment: By default it is giving a fragment with search icon but dont know to change that icon and text on this